# Java EE Application - Copy folder from war to file system with

Tags: java-ee-6, war, file-copying

I have a Java EE application which is packaged as a war file.
Under WEB-INF/classes/ I have a config folder which should be copied at startup of the Java EE application into the file system.

```
String[] filesToCopy = {"foo", ...};
for (String fileName : filesToCopy) {
    URL resource = classLoader.getResource(CONFIG_FOLDER_IN_WAR + fileName);
    File targetFile = new File(configFolderPath, fileName);
    org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyURLToFile(resource, targetFile);
}
```

that was working so far. But now the config folder contains also subfolders and a lot of files so that I don't want to list them manually.

Is there a way to copy the whole folder incl. all subfolders?

Answer (score 1):

Because I couldn't find a better solution I did it by myself and put it in my own FileUtils:

```
public static void copyFromWarToFolder(String folderInWar, File targetFolder) {
    try {
        URL resource = FileUtils.class.getClassLoader().getResource(folderInWar);
        VirtualFile virtualFileOrFolder = VFS.getChild(resource.toURI());
        copyFromWarToFolder(virtualFileOrFolder, targetFolder);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static void copyFromWarToFolder(VirtualFile virtualFileOrFolder, File targetFolder) throws Exception {
    if (virtualFileOrFolder.isDirectory()) {
        File innerTargetFolder = new File(targetFolder, virtualFileOrFolder.getName());
        innerTargetFolder.mkdir();
        for (VirtualFile innerFileOrFolder : virtualFileOrFolder.getChildren()) {
            copyFromWarToFolder(innerFileOrFolder, innerTargetFolder);
        }
    } else {
        org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyURLToFile(virtualFileOrFolder.asFileURL(), new File(targetFolder, virtualFileOrFolder.getName()));
    }
}
```